# KDE plots in Jupyter notebook Python 3 (ipykernel)

Tags: python, seaborn

I have used the following code for getting a joint plot with Kind as KDE.

```
sns.jointplot(x='Age', y='Daily Time Spent on Site', data = ad_data, color='red', kind = 'kde')
```

and getting this type of plot - [image]

where as I need this type of image - [image]

Comment: Did you check the docs? Isn't there an option  to set `fill=True`?

Comment: thanx for the same, it worked